# How can I write a variable of a user-defined type into a stream

Tags: c++, class-design

I dont mean a variable in a class but a default value for the class as a whole.

```
struct Scalar {
    unsigned int value;

    void toThePowerOf(int power);
    // etc.
}
```

I'd like to be able to do something like

```
Scaler foo;
foo.value = 2;
foo.toThePowerOf(2);

std::cout << foo << std::endl; // Outputs 4!
```

Is that possible in C++?

Comment: You already can write that. What am I missing?

Comment: Phil, I have changed the title of the question to what I think better reflects what you are struggling to ask. Feel free to improve your question if I misunderstood what you wanted.

Comment: Yep no problem, I didn't quite know what to ask.

Comment: You need to properly @address people in comment replies, or your replies won't show up in their account's Responses tab. (I only saw this one by accident.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I meant a default value for the class, so if you called that object by just its name `foo` it would return `foo.value` by default.

It is actually possible to define an implicit conversion from `Scalar` to `int`:

```
struct Scalar
{
    unsigned int value;

    operator int() const
    {
        return value;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Scalar foo = {2};
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
}
```

But implicit conversions are generally frowned upon in the C++ community, because it can make code quite hard to read. (I guess this is why noone mentioned conversion operators yet.)

Comment: ooo looks interesting I'll give it shot.

Answer (score 1):

No, classes do not have a value in the way you're thinking.

What you probably mean to do is to overload the << operator:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Scalar& val)
{
  output << val.value;
  return output;
}
```

Comment: I take it ostream should be friended?

Comment: @PhilCK: no. All we're doing is calling the version of `operator<<` that `ostream` has for the type of `val.value` (in this case `unsigned int`). It doesn't need to be a friend of us, and we don't need to be a friend of it, because neither of us is accessing anything private in the other.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot but you can overload operator << for your class and ostream to get the desired effect

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Scaler& foo)
{
   return out << foo.value;
}
```

Your code will now work and produce the desires result

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it is possible. Just initialize all the values in the constructor of the class. Use class instead of struct.

Comment: Using struct is fine, even preferred by some.

Answer (score 0):

Use a default value in the ctor.  Make the ctor explicit if you don't want implicit conversions.

```
struct Scalar {
  unsigned int value;

  Scalar(int value=0) : value (value) {}

  void toThePowerOf(int power) {
    // naive implementation just for show
    int new_value = 1;
    assert(power >= 0);  // or other error checking
    for (; power > 0; --power) {
      new_value *= value;
    }
    value = new_value;
  }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, Scalar const &x) {
    out << x.value;
    return out;
  }
};
```